# how to display duplicates keys in hashmap javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem concerning my hashMap in JS. I have some properties "keys" that are repeated several times but at least in my hashMap I find only the last one.

Example : let suppose we have this list of keys `( 12345, 12346, 12346, 12346, 12347)` and for each one I attribute some values

```
12345 <= 1
12346 <= 2
12346 <= 1
12346 <= 3
12347 <= 4
```

At the final it displays : `12345 : 1, 12346:3 , 12347:4` . But I need also those informations `12346 : 1, 12346 : 2` in my HashMap. How to fix it? 
Here is my code :

```
getFacing: function(iSceneGraph){
                var facingArray = {};
                if (iSceneGraph.children.length >0){
                    for (var i = 0; i < iSceneGraph.children.length; i++){
                        facingArray = Object.assign(facingArray, this.getFacing(iSceneGraph.children[i]));
                    }
                }
                if (iSceneGraph.merch.type === "Facing"){
                    facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] = iSceneGraph.merch.hcount;
                }
                return facingArray;
            }
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is not possible as in a map the keys are unique and duplicates are not possible. Can you have the value as an array like `12346 : [2,1,3]`

Comment: You can't have duplicated keys in a HashMap,  you should re-think your problem

Comment: It is not allowed to have duplicated keys in a HashMap. You have to use another structure. May be an Array containing the key-value-pairs: `[{"12345": 1}, {"12346": 2}, ...]`

Answer (score 1):

```
**Try this i think this will help you**
<script type="text/javascript">
var animals = ['Cow', 'Cow', 'Dog', 'Cat','Cow'];
var sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao','Moo'];
var arr = [];

for(i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    var hash = {};
    hash[animals[i]] = sounds[i];
    arr.push(hash);
}

console.log(arr);

</script>
```